# Stuck on a simple code

Tags: php, database, csv, error-handling, fopen

I have a code for open and read a csv file which is fopen() method.
But it is showing error. below is the code

```
<?php
$file = fopen('C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\testbad\testbed_information.csv', `r`);
?>
```

And the error is

```
Warning: fopen(C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\testbad\testbed_information.csv): failed to open stream: No error in C:\wamp64\www\date.php on line 2
```

Please help me...!!?

Comment: The question's title violates the basic rules of asking questions in Stackoverflow, and also you did not say what did you try and fail with, or what did you research for. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issue with quotation. You are using back-quotes in second params. change it with double or single quote

```
<?php
$file = fopen('C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\testbad\testbed_information.csv', "r");
?>
```